# How to block access to objects from outside the library?

Tags: android, public, package-private

I am developing a library has too many objects on android. So I must group the classes with package. I want to access A class from C but I want to prevent this objects accessible from Project X. So I can't use private-package (default) and "public" identifiers.

```
--PROJECT X (The project that uses the library.)
    --library src
         ---packagex
             ----Class A
             ----Class B
         ---packagey
             ----Class C
```

Is it possible ? Is there anyway to group classes without package?
Thanks.

Comment: Move class C to packagex and use default or you have to create packagexy which contains Class A, Packagex and Packagey

Comment: There are too many objects on project. It is very difficult to work without grouping. Thanks for answer

Comment: _There are too many objects on project._  What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your question.  Packages are the best way to organize your classes.  You can access A from C without exposing A to anything else.  You do this by importing the class from the package and then controlling access of usage(use private, final).  Just import com.someuser.packageX.classA at the start of Class C.  Are you anticipating some potential override or conflict? are you planning to use class C in a way that could cause the same? If not, my guess is you will never run into a problem.

Comment: I can' t access A from C without make public to A. if I make public to A, A is accessible from outside the library.

Comment: @pathfinderelite, There are too many classes in the project. That's why I can not work without grouping.

Comment: When you need Class A as common, creating a parent package does make sence and also it is well grouped. Create packageXY which contains Class A, PackageX and PackageY so that class A is accessible to both packages.

Comment: I found solution with proguard.  Now, C class accessible from  A, but not accessible from X Project.